# How to write query to my Cloudant database?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

I am trying to achieve the right query for my NoSQL database, but I am confused how to do it in Cloudant. In SQL with be

```
SELECT * FROM mydb
WHERE user_permit_doc_id = 10 
AND user_tracking_id = 1
```

My query is like:

```
https://293e2cb7-3561-4004-a1c3-58d54f517ee6-bluemix.cloudant.com/user_files/_design/user_tracking/_view/new-view?startkey=["user_permit_doc_id:10"]
```

and it returns all of the docs, not just the ones with this id.

this is m Map Reduce function for the View

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.user_tracking_id !== null){
        emit(doc);
    }
}
```

Example of a doc inside my database of docs

```
{
  "_id": "6e57baa78c6415beeee788bc786cc53a",
  "_rev": "5-f15352bce99c307bd246bda4dc0da75a",
  "user_tracking_id": "1",
  "user_permit_id": "2",
  "user_permit_doc_id": "10",
  "user_id": "1",
  "_attachments": {
    "6y41j4i68cic.jpg": {
      "content_type": "image/jpeg",
      "revpos": 2,
      "digest": "md5-KC+G5tbz2UWZSzlPHvBy/Q==",
      "length": 68367,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you guys pointed me to the right direction. The query is now like https://293e2cb7-3561-4004-a1c3-58d54f517ee6-bluemix.cloudant.com/user_files/_design/user_tracking/_view/new-view?key=["1","1"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change your view into

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.user_tracking_id !== null){
    emit([user_tracking_id, user_permit_doc_id]);
  }
}
```

and then query using the complex key [1, 10]

Answer (score 4):

You would have to incorporate the `WHERE user_permit_doc_id = 10` into your map reduce function if you wanted to return only that particular document, like this:

```
function(doc) {
   if(doc.user_permit_doc_id === 10 && doc.user_tracking_id === 1){
      emit(doc);
   }
}
```

However, since you are coming over from SQL, you might be more comfortable with Mongo-like queries. If that style of querying your DB suits you better, check out the [Cloudant Mango API layer](https://github.com/cloudant/mango). This API introduces SQL-like querying to NoSQL, actually creating a map reduce function behind the scenes.

Comment: thats cool, and works of course, but this function is within the database and what I need is to query dynamically based on user input, so 10 and 1 are just examples. Is there something I need to learn before? I cannot get it right. Whats the role of the mapreduce function here?

Comment: The map reduce function retrieves documents from the DB using the conditions that you set within it. In other words, you start with all documents and the map reduce eliminates all docs that do not match the condition. You cannot query based directly on user inputs. For that, you will need to use the Mango API layer which I initially suggested.

Comment: If you're looking to do ad hoc queries (like searches), you can use Cloudant Search or the new Cloudant Query API, both of which support ad hoc queries.

"The Cloudant Query API can also be used to perform queries by POSTing to a database's _find endpoint:
`curl -X POST https://user:pass@account.cloudant.com/movies/_find 
     -d '{ "selector": { "year": 2012 }, "limit": 10}'`

https://cloudant.com/blog/cloudant-query-grows-up-to-handle-ad-hoc-queries/#.VXnsWlVVikp